# Gateway settings on multiple interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have two devices (actually not PC). Device A is connected with external network, this IP is `192.168.1.2`, I use this as gateway.
Device B has two interfaces like below. Two interfaces use the same gateway, so I set it manually. ping test fails (`ping -I eth0 www.google.com / ping -I eth1 www.google.com`)

What's wrong here?

> eth0
>
> IP : 192.168.1.1 mask : 255.255.255.252
>
> eth1
>
> IP : 192.168.1.11 mask : 255.255.255.248

Kernel IP routing table:

> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> **default         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0**
>
> **default         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1**
>
> 192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth0
>
> **192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1**
>
> 192.168.1.8     *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your gateway as being in two different places.  You are saying that is it out of eth0 at 192.168.1.2 (which is correct), but also out of eth1 at 192.168.1.2 (which is incorrect).  Not only is your gateway not available out of eth1, but the IP address isn't valid on that network.

Just remove the second gateway and it should work fine.

Comment: As you said, if I remove one, it works correctly. But it is working on only one interface. I hope that it can be used through different interface, if I try to connect different source IP using socket connection.

Comment: And I tested ping command, and captured and show pcap log. In log, outgoing and incoming packet is shown, but ping command is timeout about eth1.

Comment: What do you mean it is only working through one interface?  The gateway only exists out of one interface.  If you have other devices on 192.168.1.8 network, then you need to add routing to 192.168.1.2 to tell it to route packets for 192.168.1.8 via 192.168.1.1. Please edit your question and add more info.